# where is bitcoins?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

I have bitcoin core wallet 17.1 
I sent 85$ to `32yF1MuqbUmKsGZE7jedkZV8PVJRuimRAu` to one of my wallets but all my wallets shows 0 balance, why?
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/32yF1MuqbUmKsGZE7jedkZV8PVJRuimRAu

```
root@localhost:~/.bitcoin# bitcoin-cli validateaddress 32yF1MuqbUmKsGZE7jedkZV8PVJRuimRAu
{
  "isvalid": true,
  "address": "32yF1MuqbUmKsGZE7jedkZV8PVJRuimRAu",
  "scriptPubKey": "a9140e09b3ce08f74ab7c2a085fceef99100ecde7b7187",
  "isscript": true,
  "iswitness": false
}

root@localhost:~/.bitcoin# bitcoin-cli getbalance
0.00000000
```

Comment: "bitcoin-cli getblockcount" says what?

Comment: 235375
 I am using prune

Answer (score 1):

“getblockcount” tells you the number of blocks your node knows. If it’s not around 56000 (currently), it means you node is out of sync with the blockchain. You’ll need to wait for synchronisation to finish to see your transactions.

Comment: i am using in prune mode, is it still correct?

Comment: @Kamran Yes, you should still wait.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have another question about 'bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6' this command change the default fee or just show how much will be the fee?

Comment: @Kamran It only advises a fee setting, doesn't change anything else, as per [the documentation](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/util/estimatesmartfee/)